# How to change background color of selected tree node?

Tags: c#, .net, treenode

I have a treenode which i create dynamically as described below:
->UK,->India  ->Delhi  ->Mumbai ->USA ->Russia
I need to change the color of the node when i click on the node. As for eg if i click on delhi delhi should be highlighted, if russia then russia. etc
I call the the same when i click on the node

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NodeMouseClick` event to set the background color of the selected Node.

Define a class level `TreeNode` member

```
TreeNode node = null;
```

And use the logic given below,

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
 {
    if (null != node)
     {
         //Reset the color when selected node changes
         node.BackColor = Color.White;
     }

     //Set the currently selected node color
     e.Node.BackColor = Color.Green;

     node = e.Node;
 }
```